# Is there any Portuguese Treebank with chunked sents for NLTK?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

My problem is that I need to retrieve NP chunks from texts using NLTK, but I do not want use regex chunkers. I am new to NLP, but I think classification-based chunking (IOB tags) would be much better than regular expression chunking. I can only find chunked sents in languages that are not Portuguese (Brazil), most of them in English.

Actually, my main problem is to extract Person and Organization Entities from text, so I am first trying to get the NP chunks. But I am not sure if I am trailling the right path. Any tip would be great.